# How to change color of the font based on the thresh hold value

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, colors

I have a requirement like if the the threshhold value is greater than 6% the text color should appear as red and between 5-6% it should change to yellow. I tried this expression in the text box font color property for the first requirement iif(fields!My_column.value>6, "red","Black") but did not work. I would appreciate any tips for both of my problems. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

No reason this shouldn't be working.

You can set the **Color** property for a **Text Box** and it should be fine.

```
=Switch(Fields!My_column.Value > 6, "Red"
    , Fields!My_column.Value < 5, "Black"
    , true , "Yellow")
```

Gives:

[image]

How does your underlying data look? Is 6% "*6*" or is it actually "*0.06*"?

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks a lot. It worked! As you pointed out I forgot to pay attention to the format of the underlying data.

Comment: Cool, glad it's working! Please consider setting this as the existing answer and upvoting if you think the answer was helpful!

Comment: Can I have a similar check for date as well? I have a text box with date picker. but I am facing problem in validating date before report is fetched. also I want to make the textbox read only.