# Can we have onblur event on text for rdl(ssrs reports) files?

Tags: validation, textbox, ssrs-2008, onblur, rdl

I want to validate a textbox value and display an error message. Do we have any way to do it on focus out of text box?

Note: New to RDL and SSRS reports.

Comment: Not directly by the SSRS but you can use jquery to bind the event at runtime and do the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use this option with SSRS native, but you can change the color of the textbox to indicate that something is wrong.

Check this out [How to change color of the font based on the thresh hold value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900524/how-to-change-color-of-the-font-based-on-the-thresh-hold-value)

Comment: I have a editable text box which fills long date. How can I validate the date?